# ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint (error)

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Flight (
FlightNo int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FlightDate Date,
PlaneSerialNo int,
EmployeeID int,
RouteNo int,
CONSTRAINT FK_PlaneSerialNo FOREIGN KEY(PlaneSerialNo)
REFERENCES Plane(PlaneSerialNo),
CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeID FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID)
REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID),
CONSTRAINT FK_RouteNo FOREIGN KEY(RouteNo)
REFERENCES Route(RouteNo)
);
```

trying to create a sort of database system using oracle where it tracks flights but it just says the name is already used but havent seen any similarities in constraints other than identifying FKs

Comment: for the best support/answers, ALWAYS provide the exact error message in your questions

Comment: Is 'sort of' a database system anything like being 'sort of' pregnant?  :-)   Just as an aside, in oracle names are case insensitive.  That being the case, we tend to not use CamelCase names.  Instead we tend to use underscore_delimited names.  So, instead of 'FlightNo', we'd use 'flight_no'.  It may seem like nit-picking personal preference, but it pays rewards when you start looking at the actual values in the data dictionary and come across things like 'PLANESERIALNO', where you'd probably prefer PLANE_SERIAL_NO.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't rely much on *similarities* - it has found object with **exactly** the same name in its dictionary and - as you can't have two objects with the same name - it raised the error.

Query `user_constraints` (and then `user_objects`, if previous search didn't find anything).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out which table it is, you might try

```
select owner, table_name from dba_constraints where constraint_name = '<some value from your create table command>';
```